# Certificate Template Purpose Unknown

Tags: active-directory, certificate, templates

I am facing a strange issue with one certificate template. In CA console under certificate template box, it is showing with cross sign with “Unknown” as it’s intended purpose and neither I am able to see any attribute information or properties of this particular template from AD certificate template container. It’s totally blank there as well.

This particular template was designed for ocsp signing certificates and was used recently like 2-3 months back successfully . But now it is no more viewable and thus ocsp certs not getting renewed with it.

Let me tell that we have 2 domains in the forest and this template is showing properly in Parent domain. However it is the issue in child domain and our issuing CA also in child domain.

Rest everything is working fine on the setup. Issue is with this template only.

Any guess, what could be the issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zpUZ.jpg)

Comment: This means that someone has deleted template from AD and CA fails to resolve this template.